# How to have executable JAR run on windows without JVM?

Tags: java, windows, deployment, java-service-wrapper

I need to find a way to make my java program run on computers without Java. I made a pretty simple survey/answer type program for my school, and to make it easier to use I used a wrapper (JSmooth to be specific). But it seems that for the teachers that don't have Java installed, the program does not execute. Is there a wrapper that allows for execution of Java code without the JVM installed?
I know that the thought of converting Java(Write once, run anywhere) to a specific platform-code is pretty bad, but it's necessary for my situation.

Comment: There are a lot of questions on this topic - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Comment: looks like excelsior JET might do the job

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807705/jar-to-exe-with-an-external-library/14808286#14808286).  I am surprised your teachers use only Windows based computers.  Aren't Macs popular with educators?

Comment: @lonewart A native compiler such as Excelsior JET sounds like an overkill in your situation. If JSmooth is indeed not capable or bundling a private JRE, check out the other options listed in [my article](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html#launch). But feel free to apply for a free license (Yes, I work for Excelsior.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Macs are expensive and public schools lack money :(

Answer (score 1):

There's not much that can be recommended. You might be able to find something *such as JNC or the GNU compiler* but they are out of date and your results may vary. If I were you, I would give it a shot anyway. Theres lots of existing discussion on this, just look around you'll find what you need.

**EDIT:** Take a look at [this](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html).

Answer (score -1):

Try something like the [Java Native Compiler](http://jnc.mtsystems.ch/).

EDIT:

Also see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746656/which-java-native-compilers-can-be-recommended).

Comment: Not for a few years, but the OP simply wants to get something running for a school project.  It's that or install a JRE.

Comment: There is also the GNU Java compiler.  Again, not developed in a while, but likely still usable.  http://gcc.gnu.org/java/